# how to make a horizontal line and vertical line cross

Tags: html

i cant seem to create a vertical and horizontal line that will cross in the page. they just seem to scoot each other over. any suggestions? newbie here, thanks for y'all's time!

```css
#colorstrip {
 height: 0px;
    border-bottom:solid 30px #FF8533;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#verticalLine {
    border-left: solid 12px #FF4719;
    margin-left: 480px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="verticalLine"> </div>
        <div id="colorstrip">
```

Answer (score 1):

`colorstrip` is being pushed over by `verticalLine`.  Just add `position:absolute;` and it will fix it.  Just be careful, absolute positioning can make things very messy very fast.

```css
#colorstrip {
 height: 0px;
    border-bottom:solid 30px #FF8533;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#verticalLine {
    position:absolute;
    border-left: solid 12px #FF4719;
    margin-left: 480px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="verticalLine"> </div>
        <div id="colorstrip">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to intersecting lines to meet in the page. One way to set it up would be like this.

```
   #verticalLine{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:50%;
 width:10px;
 height:100%;
 background-color:#FF4719;
 
}

#colorstrip{
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 width:0;
 height:10px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#FF8533;
 
}
    <div id="verticalLine"></div>
    <div id="colorstrip"></div>
```

Normal elements on a page behave like text, two elements will show up one after the other.

Position: absolute takes the div out of the normal order of the page and lays it above everything else ignoring just about everything else. 
When you have a position: absolute element you can use top,left,bottom,and right to control its position on the page.

top:0 is 0 pixels from the top, left: 50% starts the div 50% from the left. (note starting at 50% does not mean its centered to the page)
The rest is the size of the color bar, and the color.

There are other ways of achieving this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a bin , basically have a parent div and put a css for two childs that is vertical and horizontal line below parent div

https://jsbin.com/maxiqetama/edit?html,css,output